# Xamarin with Entity Framework Core: Error: unauthorized access to "/system/lib/libsqlite.so" on Android 7

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.android, entity-framework-core

Im trying to create a Xamarin Forms App using the new Entity Framework Core. The app targets android 6.0 but my Emulator is running Android 7.0. I installed the following related Nuget packages on the android project:

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore --> 1.1.1
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite --> 1.1.1

When accessing my DbContext on Android a message will pop up telling: Detected problems with native libraries unauthorized access to "/system/lib/libsqlite.so".

[This](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/78234/android-libmonosgen-library-sqlite-problems-with-app-native-libraries) Xamarin forums thread suggests, that it's due to the native SqLite binaries are no longer supported (on Android 7?) and the common fix seems to be to switch to the SqLite.Net PCL.

However as Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite depends on Microsoft.Data.Sqlite which in turn depends on the native SqLite package I cannot just replace this (or can I?)

Strangely enough, despite of the error message suggesting otherwise, the data access seems to work. At least migrations run and repeated writes to the database will create new Ids.

Of course I could just scrap EF Core but I guess a lot of people are looking into using it for Xamarin in the future. So it would be nice if anyone would find/know a fix.

Comment: I don't see why you are using EF to access SQLite, SQLite.NET PCL already provides easy access to database.

Comment: Two words: code-first. It has a lot of advantadges being able to model your database in code. Also migrations make evolving your datamodel really easy and save. Even after deployment with updates.

Comment: It's a [known issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/7777). You can get the nightly build to avoid the problem.

Comment: You can do code-first database in SQLite.NET PCL without EF, see example here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/data/part_3_using_sqlite_orm/

Comment: @Alexandre That's good to know. Please note, that the (current) version referenced in the article (SQLite.NET with a dot) suffers from the same problem and will produce the same error on android N

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I have fixed this using the following libs: sqlite-net-pcl (version 1.2.0), SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green, SQLitePCLRaw.core, SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3.android, SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3.android.

Comment: This IS the solution but - what about the entity-framework dependencies on the native sqlite binaries.

Comment: did you just reference them or do you have to setup them up somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Matheus Souza had the right idea there. However installing SQLitePCL is only part of the answer. Here is how I eventually solved this:

**DISCLAIMER**: This is a kind of "You can do it but it isn't pretty"-solution. If you have the time, it's probably best to wait for the official Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite 1.2.0 release.

[This](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/7777) issue brought me on the right track. The new (unreleased) version of EntityFrameworkCore no longer uses the native sqlite binaries, but sqlite-net-pcl. This is the steps I followed to install it:

1. Add the [aspnetcore-dev branch](https://dotnet.myget.org/gallery/aspnetcore-dev) to your nuget feeds. Nuget 3: `https://dotnet.myget.org/F/aspnetcore-dev/api/v3/index.json`
2. Check "Show preview versions" in Nuget and update (or reinstall) all EntityFrameworkCore packages to "1.2.0 - preview"
3. (Make sure your x64 is checked in your android projects advanced build options, if the app instantly crashes on deploy. This might be unreleated)

Comment: I upgraded Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite to 2.0.0 preview-1 , but after that , Android app crashes ...

Comment: @paradise_human Is your emulator x86 or x64? Make sure to make the setting in step 3 accordingly.

Comment: My emulator is X86_64. when I check x86_64 in my advance option my app stick in splashView and a white screen shows me .

Comment: I checked X86 and X86_64. When I run the app I got this error in debug mode : Stack walks are not supported on this platform.
How can I solve ?

Comment: I installed the preview1-final of EF.SQLite but I encounter the following when deploying to a emulator: Could not load assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe' during startup registration.
This might be due to an invalid debug installation.